# How to extract specific strings from a XML file that share the same tag as other strings?

Tags: xml, linux, xpath, xmlstarlet

In the following XML snippet...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/static/atom.xsl"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:s="http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <title>serverclients</title>
  <id>https://splfwdprw2:8089/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients</id>
  <updated>2017-04-04T16:14:04-04:00</updated>
  <generator build="f3e41e4b37b2" version="6.3.1"/>
  <author>
    <name>Splunk</name>
  </author>
  <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/_acl" rel="_acl"/>
  <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/countClients_by_machineType" rel="countClients_by_machineType"/>
  <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/countRecentDownloads" rel="countRecentDownloads"/>
  <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/getMatchingAppsForClient_dryRun" rel="getMatchingAppsForClient_dryRun"/>
  <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/preview" rel="preview"/>
  <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage>18446744073709551615</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
  <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <s:messages/>
  <entry>
    <title>00031e8f6c883544b8079037c5eba9ec</title>
    <id>https://splfwdprw2:8089/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/00031e8f6c883544b8079037c5eba9ec</id>
    <updated>2017-04-04T16:14:04-04:00</updated>
    <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/00031e8f6c883544b8079037c5eba9ec" rel="alternate"/>
    <author>
      <name>system</name>
    </author>
    <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/00031e8f6c883544b8079037c5eba9ec" rel="list"/>
    <link href="/servicesNS/nobody/search/deployment/server/clients/00031e8f6c883544b8079037c5eba9ec" rel="remove"/>
    <content type="text/xml">
      <s:dict>
        <s:key name="applications">
          <s:dict>
            <s:key name="all_deploymentclient">
              <s:dict>
                <s:key name="action">Phonehome</s:key>
                <s:key name="archive">/opt/splunk/var/run/tmp/all_deploymentclient/all_deploymentclient-1491320471.bundle</s:key>
                <s:key name="checksum">0</s:key>
                <s:key name="excludeFromUpdate"></s:key>
                <s:key name="failedReason"></s:key>
                <s:key name="issueReload">0</s:key>
                <s:key name="restartSplunkWeb">0</s:key>
                <s:key name="restartSplunkd">1</s:key>
                <s:key name="result">Ok</s:key>
                <s:key name="serverclasses">
                  <s:list>
                    <s:item>all_deploymentclient</s:item>
                  </s:list>
                </s:key>
                <s:key name="size">10240</s:key>
                <s:key name="stateOnClient">enabled</s:key>
                <s:key name="timestamp">Tue Apr  4 11:42:54 2017</s:key>
              </s:dict>
            </s:key>
            <s:key name="all_fwd_outputs_18indexers">
              <s:dict>
                <s:key name="action">Phonehome</s:key>
                <s:key name="archive">/opt/splunk/var/run/tmp/all_fwd/all_fwd_outputs_18indexers-1491320471.bundle</s:key>
                <s:key name="checksum">0</s:key>
                <s:key name="excludeFromUpdate"></s:key>
                <s:key name="failedReason"></s:key>
                <s:key name="issueReload">0</s:key>
                <s:key name="restartSplunkWeb">0</s:key>
                <s:key name="restartSplunkd">1</s:key>
                <s:key name="result">Ok</s:key>
                <s:key name="serverclasses">
                  <s:list>
                    <s:item>all_fwd</s:item>
                  </s:list>
                </s:key>
                <s:key name="size">10240</s:key>
                <s:key name="stateOnClient">enabled</s:key>
                <s:key name="timestamp">Tue Apr  4 11:42:54 2017</s:key>
              </s:dict>
            </s:key>
```

...I'm attempting to extract any "s:key name=" strings that appear in the first level below the "s:key name="applications" tag. In this example, the strings I'm looking to extract are "all_deploymentclient" and "all_fwd_outputs_18indexers". If additional strings were to appear on the same level, I would want to capture those as well.

I'm working with xml_grep, but I'm unsure as to how I can define the arguments in order get the desired result (as there are multiple instances of the "s:key name=" tag with some of them serving as a type of heading, and others with a value assigned to them).

So, when it's all said and done, the extraction output for this example should be:

```
all_deploymentclient
all_fwd_outputs_18indexers
```

How can I accomplish this? Is another utility (such as xpath) required?

Comment: Is your "XML snippet" complete? Is the prefix `s` bound anywhere? (Like `xmlns:s="some namespace uri"`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking into consideration the information provided by @MichaelKay and @knb, I was able to determine a solution. I ended up using `xmlstarlet` to get the information I needed as follows:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//*[local-name()='key'][@name='applications']/*/*/@name" -v . -n <XML filename>
```

This produced the following output:

```
all_deploymentclient
all_fwd_outputs_18indexers
```

Thanks to everyone for their contributions!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this first (quick and dirty method to replace `s:` namespace prefixes):

```
cat /var/tmp/content.xml | sed 's/s://g' > cat /var/tmp/content2.xml
```

Then try

```
xmllint  --xpath "//key[@name='all_deploymentclient' or @name='all_fwd_outputs_18indexers']/@name" /var/tmp/content2.xml \
| sed "s| name|\nname|g; s/name=\"//; s/\"\$//"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! When I read your reply, I realized that I wasn't describing my issue clearly enough, so I've edited the description of my issue accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you do any kind of search of any kind of data source, it's not enough to know what the actual data is (if you knew, you wouldn't need to search it): you need to know in what way it might differ from the example shown.

So we have to look at your description of the problem: "s:key name=" strings that appear in the indentation after the "s:key name="applications" tag", and try and understand what you mean by it.

- By indentation, do you literally mean the paginated layout, or is this your way of talking about the tree structure of the XML data model?
- When you say "after", are we to interpret this (based on your example) as meaning "first descendant" elements, that is, the first matching descendants that we encounter in a tree walk?

Can we assume that these "first descendants" will always be two levels down from the origin node (i.e. grandchildren?). If so, the XPath solution is simply

```
//s:key[@name="applications"]/*/*/@name
```

But if the "first descendants" might be at different depths, then it becomes rather more difficult, and the solution might also depend which version of XPath you are using. So we need more information.

I've no idea what xml_grep is capable of.

Comment: You've broken down my issue quite extensively. I just modified the XML snippet to include the beginning of the code (in order for everyone to see the full picture). To answer the questions @MichaelKay posed: "indentation" is my clumsy way of describing how each level of tags are placed in the code. So, if `<s:key name="applications">` is the "parent", then `<s:key name="all_deploymentclient">` would be the "child" (one level down). The child level is what I'm interested in collecting; I'm not going down any further levels.